# Kivy to apk issue library

Tags: python, kivy

Hello I want to convert kivy app to apk application but I was imported some librarys another kivy the question is the lib can be run on android such as cryptography , requests , sockets or specific library will be run or not run another library just kivy

And if not there are methods to run this library in apk ?
Like this ..
This library will be run ??
"
import requests
import cryptography
from kivy.app import App
"

Comment: Can you please use some punctuation? It's really hard for me to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Can I run another library python in kivy app for android applications?

Comment: Like requests,  sockets, cryptography,

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Dr-shell**, It's very easy to run almost any library in your applications. Just add them in the  `requirements` section of your buildozer.spec file.

**For example:-**

```
requirements = kivy, requests, cryptography
```

**For more clarification Please refer to [Buildozer Docs](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Use python-for-android (https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) if the used library is in the recipes (https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes) it should work without any pain.

p4a apk creates the apk if you have a .p4a file.